# iOS add the "Add Widget" on 3D touch

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

In developing a new iOS app with a Today-Extension (Widget), I cannot find the documentation on how to add the "Add Widget" link in the top right of the widget pop-up under 3D touch (Quick Action / Force Touch).
This all came about because during my testing I deleted the widget from the Today / Notification screen and couldn't get it back. I've attached a screenshot of a non-Apple app that has a widget pop-up on 3D touch with the "Add Widget" functionality I'm looking for. Cheers.
[add widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFmp3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer eventually. Turns out in Xcode I was targeting the app extension with my builds and not the app itself. Seems like a minor detail, and it was a very subtle error on my part. So for anyone on the same path as I was, look in the toolbar of Xcode and ensure you launch your app with CMD+R and not just your app extension.